# I am having trouble getting my comments to post

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-router-dom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIuur.png)I am having trouble getting my comments to post. Can someone look at my codes and give me some feedback?

Whenever I post a comment, the screen flashes but nothing posts. I tested the back-end functions on Postman and everything there works fine so I'm assuming something isn't working properly in the front end.

I've tried everything I can. Fairly new to coding and not sure what to try next.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!loggedIn) {
        navigate.push('/login')
    }
    return () => {
        setErrors([])
    }
}, [loggedIn, setContent, navigate, setErrors])

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefaul();
    const newContent = {
        content: content,
        blog_id: blog.id
    }
    fetch('/comments', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newContent)
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
        if(data.errors) {
            setErrors(data.errors)
        } else {
            addComment(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So it sounds like you are saying the POST request works, and that you have some issue afterwards. Can you [edit] to clarify what this specific issue is after successfully POSTing an update to the backend? What specifically isn't working as expected? Can you provide more details and clarity, and a more complete [mcve] for us to examine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you misstyped `preventDefault` just below the function declaration of `handleSubmit` you wrote `e.preventDefaul()`. While I cannot see the rest of your component what I assume is happening, is that the forms submits which triggers a reload and stops the promise from sending. Fixing this typo will probably fix your problem.

Comment: OMG Thank you. I don't know how I didn't catch that.. It works! thanks!

Comment: For future reference, issues caused by typos have their own vote close reason. This is because these sort of problems only help one person really and aren't of much value to future readers.